# How to protect CustomTaskPane from resize?

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

I am developing Outlook add-in.

How to restrict CustomTaskPanes size change. I set MinWidth and MaxWidth, but this has no effect.

Is it possible to set minimum height? Which will limit also the parent window size?

Answer (score 0):

Do you develop a Custom Task Pane or Outlook Form Region?

Did you try to handle SizeChanged or [Resized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize(v=vs.110).aspx) event?

In the Resized event handler you may check out the current values and set your own values.

Comment: CustomTaskPane. Works very ugly. This way: http://office-outlook.com/outlook-forum/index.php/t/76259/

Comment: Why do you need to use task panes instead of form regions?

Comment: Why should I use Form Regions if I even cannot dock them left/right? I see that the only option is "adjoining bottom".